# Is it possible to get only hidden text of an element?

Tags: javascript, css, html, selenium, webdriver

Selenium Webdriver contains a function that returns only visible text inside element. I'd want to write a function that will get only hidden text inside element (i.e. all text that isn't visible [in meaning of Selenium Webdriver W3C spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/#determining-visibility)). According to to this spec element is visible only if all following conditions are met:

> - The element must have a height and width greater than 0px.
> - The element must not be visible if that element, or any of its ancestors, is hidden or has a CSS display property that is none.
> - The element must not be visible if there is a CSS3 Transform property that moves the element out of the viewport and can not be scrolled to.
>     OPTIONs and OPTGROUP elements are treated as special cases, they are considered shown if and only if the enclosing select element is visible.
> - MAP elements are shown if and only if the image it uses is visible. Areas within a map are shown if the enclosing MAP is visible.
> - Any INPUT elements of "type=hidden" are not visible
> - Any NOSCRIPT elements must not be visible if Javascript is enabled.
> - The element must not be visible if any ancestor in the element's transitive closure of offsetParents has a fixed size, and has the CSS style of "overflow:hidden", and the element's location is not within the fixed size of the parent.

Is it possible to write a JS function that will return only hidden text contained inside element? Do you know of any library that contains such function? How slow will such function be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to write such code if you are just monitoring for `display: none`, `visibility: hidden` and no size or even an absolute/relative position that is off the screen.  You would have to iterate every element in the page, determine if the element is visible and, if so, collect the text from any text nodes in that element.

It will be no slower or faster than any other function that iterates every node in the document.  The total time will depend upon how efficiently the iteration code is written (it can skip all children of a hidden element for example) and on how long/complicated the document is.

If you want to be able to tell the difference between text that is outside the edges of an element with overflow:hidden or elements that might be marked for visibility, but be off-screen or out of view or out of the current viewable scroll area or pieces of text that might be obscured by other elements, that would be very difficult and honestly I don't know if all of that can be figured out from pure javascript.